# $\int_0^t W_s \, ds $ has finite variation

Tags: brownian-motion, quadratic-variation

Let $W=\{W_t:t \geq 0\}$ be a standard Brownian motion and consider
$$X_t=\int_0^t W_s \, ds$$

We define the variation of a process $X_t$ has
$$Var[X]_t=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{i=1}^n |X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}}|$$
with $t_i=\frac{t}{n}i$.

How do I compute $Var[X]_t$ ?

In particular, why is it finite?

Comment: Hint: if $f \in C^1([0,T])$ then it has finite variation on $[0,T]$ given by $V(f)_T = \int_0^T |f'(t)|\, dt$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum_i^n |X_{t_{i+1}}-X_{t_i}|=\sum_i^n\left|\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} W_sds\right|\leq \sum_i^n\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} |W_s|ds=\int_0^t|W_s|ds<\infty$$

Comment: This mights be a stupid question but why is the last term finite?